# babel, and create-react-app blocked by group policy windows 10

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, group-policy

When trying to run the  `create-react-a-app` or 'babel' command in command line, I get the error:

> This program has been blocked by group policy

I have been unable to find the offending policy on my machine using the group policy editor.

could not find any solutions online so far. Would greatly appreciate being pointed in the right direction here.

Comment: More information is needed. Are you in a domain environment?

Comment: I am not in a domain environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this:

I got the exact same error. Thought it was my company's policies that prevented npx.

First I ran `set-execution policy` as an administrator in power shell. Then I remembered that I had already create one project with npx. Apparently I had used the same name for that project. After changing the project name, everything ran smoothly.

Not sure if the `set-execution policy` step is necessary, but I ran it and it worked.